# Degree Parameter for SVM Polynomial Kernel

Tags: svm, polynomial

For Support Vector Machines, what effect does the degree parameter have on a model, when using a polynomial kernel?

I was able to [find an intuitive explanation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-rbf-parameters-py) of the influence of cost and gamma model parameters, but not the effect of the degree parameter when using a polynomial kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the degree parameter controls the flexibility of the decision boundary. Higher degree kernels yield a more flexible decision boundary.

Ben-Hur, Asa, and Jason Weston. "A user’s guide to support vector machines." In Data mining techniques for the life sciences, pp. 231. Humana Press, 2010.